# GraphDB + Keycloak behind proxy

Tags: docker-compose, keycloak, reverse-proxy, graphdb

I am trying to deploy an application that uses Keycloak as an authentication service and GraphDB as repository. The application is running behind a proxy and I am having trouble setting up the OpenID configuration in GraphDB. I created a minimal example with just Keycloak, GraphDB and nginx proxy (`custom-nginx` just contains a `nginx.conf` with reverse proxy declarations for the services):

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
  nginx:
    build:
      context: nginx
    image: custom-nginx
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    depends_on:
      - auth-server
      - db-server
  auth-server-db:
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB:
      POSTGRES_USER:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD:
    volumes:
      - auth-server-db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  auth-server:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:22.0
    command:
      - start
    environment:
      KC_HOSTNAME_URL: ${URL}/auth
      KC_HOSTNAME_ADMIN_URL: ${URL}/auth/
      KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT_BACKCHANNEL: false
      KC_PROXY: edge
      KC_HTTP_ENABLED: true
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: ${KC_ADMIN_PASS}
      DB_VENDOR: POSTGRES
      DB_ADDR: auth-server-db
      DB_DATABASE: ${POSTGRES_DB}
      DB_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
      DB_SCHEMA: public
      DB_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:8088:8080"
    volumes:
      - auth-server:/opt/keycloak/data
    depends_on:
      - auth-server-db
  db-server:
    image: ontotext/graphdb:10.3.2
    depends_on:
        - auth-server
    environment:
      GDB_JAVA_OPTS: -Dgraphdb.external-url=${URL}/db-server -Dgraphdb.auth.methods=openid -Dgraphdb.auth.openid.issuer=http://auth-server:8080/realms/termit -Dgraphdb.auth.openid.token_issuer=${URL}/auth/realms/termit -Dgraphdb.auth.openid.client_id=${GDB_CLIENTID} -Dgraphdb.auth.openid.username_claim=preferred_username -Dgraphdb.auth.openid.auth_flow=code -Dgraphdb.auth.openid.token_type=access -Dgraphdb.auth.openid.proxy=true -Ddefault.min.distinct.threshold=67108864 -Dgraphdb.workbench.cors.enable=true -Dgraphdb.workbench.cors.origin=* -Dgraphdb.workbench.cors.expose-headers=*
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:7200:7200"
    volumes:
      - db-server:/opt/graphdb/home
volumes:
  auth-server-db:
  auth-server:
  db-server:
```

When I try this setup with GraphDB, I get the following error:
`The Issuer "http://localhost/auth/realms/termit" provided in the configuration did not match the requested issuer "http://auth-server:8080/realms/termit"`. But if I set the issuer URI to localhost, it cannot connect to it.

My experience with Spring-based applications behind a proxy is that I would set JWT issuer URI to the **public URL** of the authentication server (e.g., `http://localhost/auth/realms/termit`) and JWK Set URI to the **internal Docker service URL**. Is there any similar setting in GraphDB so that I could get both services working behind a proxy (in Docker)?

Any help or examples are much appreciated. Thanks

The `nginx.conf` contains the following:

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    client_max_body_size 25M;

    include mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name  localhost;

        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;

        location /auth/ {
            proxy_pass http://auth-server:8080/;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $http_x_forwarded_port;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Cookie $http_cookie;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

            # Increase buffer sizes to handle large headers sent by Keycloak and its clients
            proxy_buffer_size   128k;
            proxy_buffers       4 256k;
            proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
        }

        location = /db-server {
            return 302 /db-server/;
        }

        location /db-server/ {
            rewrite ^/graphdb/(.*) /$1 break;
            proxy_pass http://db-server:7200;
            proxy_redirect http://db-server:7200/ /db-server/;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:
I was able to get the configuration working, although not the way I was hoping to achieve. My working setup (minimal sample can be found with explanation on [GitHub](https://github.com/ledsoft/keycloak-graphdb-nginx)) configures GraphDB to access Keycloak via its public URL (e.g., http://172.17.0.1/auth) instead of the Docker service URL (http://auth-server:8080).

On Keycloak's side it is necessary to configure the client with `public` access and ensure that the access token contains roles and audience claim.

For local testing, it is not possible to use `http://localhost` as public URL because the services interpret the URL as localhost **within** the service's container instead of the Docker host (my computer). Instead, I used `http://172.17.0.1` which is the [network interface created by Docker on the host system](https://docs.docker.com/network/drivers/bridge/) (IP may vary per system).

Answer (score 0):

The problem if I understand it well, Keycloak will use it's own url to issue token *'localhost'*, GraphDB using proxy will use proxy url *'auth-server:8080'*.

For GraphDB, make sure the public facing URL (the issuer) is set to http://localhost/auth/realms/termit.
For internal calls, GraphDB will need to access Keycloak using an internal Docker network address: http://auth-server:8080. But it should validate tokens based on the public facing URL.

Also, be sure that KC_HOSTNAME_URL is your public URL : http://localhost/auth.

Edit after comment :

Only relationnal database are supported https://www.keycloak.org/server/db

Maybe you could try to write an intermediate mirco service, use it as a [*'Custom  Keycloak Provider'*](https://www.baeldung.com/java-keycloak-custom-user-providers) and make link yourself.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I am trying to do, but I can't seem to find the appropriate configuration options in GraphDB docs.

Comment: Also, after reading documentation it seems that only relational database are supported : https://www.keycloak.org/server/db

Comment: This has nothing to do with Keycloak's database. GraphDB acts as a Resource server in the scenario.

Comment: By ressource you mean users ?

Comment: No, I mean [OAuth2/OIDC resource server](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/the-resource-server/)

Comment: Oh ok my bad I should have read your post better :) 'DB_VENDOR: POSTGRES'. I will look at this with this new angle ^^

Comment: Hey, I found this 'graphdb.auth.openid.issuer' in the documentation, that might help :)
https://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/10.0/access-control.html#openid-oauth

Comment: Hi, I did use this configuration property. It can be seen in the `GDB_JAVA_OPTS` environment variable. But as I describe in the post, it did not work for me...

Comment: You have two different configuration which is strange : "-Dgraphdb.auth.openid.issuer=http://auth-server:8080/realms/termit -Dgraphdb.auth.openid.token_issuer=${URL}/auth/realms/termit "

You should only have : " -Dgraphdb.auth.openid.issuer=${URL}/auth/realms/termit "

Comment: Yes I know. But when I use the ${URL}, which is the public URL of the whole system, it tries to reach Keycloak via this public URL. I would rather reach Keycloak via its Docker service URL. As I said in the post, Spring applications allow doing that - use one URL for reaching Keycloak (the Docker service URL) and another for validating the token issuer (the public URL). I was hoping to be able to do something similar, because the public URL causes issues with access (on localhost) or certificates for me.

Comment: Ok, I got it.. ^^ 
So for me you cannot do that in GraphDb, link to the documentation that I provided in the previous comment is clear. 

Maybe you can try an ugly work around with nginx by reformatting the request, if the required issuer is transmitted in the request (of course not the one in JWT)

Comment: I was hoping to be able to use the two separate configuration parameters to get this to work, but apparently their purpose is different (and it escapes me). Thanks for you effort, though!

Comment: With pleasure, if you find something to make it works let me know I am interested :)